# JWT: what is the advantage of a refresh token when using grant_type=password

Tags: oauth, access-token, jwt, refresh-token

I'm following [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) to understand refesh tokens.

In my case I have to connect to REST api using grant_type=password, and I receive a token with a 5 minute lifespan. So every 5 minutes I have to issue a POST request passing client-id, username & password to get a new acces token.

The other option would be to issue a POST with a grant_type=refresh_token, without having to send the username & password. In my case I'm consuming an api, so passing the credentials doesn't involve any action from the final user. For me it's just to params more to send on the POST request.

In both cases, I have to issue a new post every 5 minutes.

Is that the only advantage (not needing to pass credentials again) of using the reresh token or is there any other thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

## Background info

[OAuth 2.0 Password Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/)

> The Password grant type is a way to exchange a user's credentials for an access token. Because the client application has to collect the user's password and send it to the authorization server, it is not recommended that this grant be used at all anymore.

[OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/refresh-token/)

> The Refresh Token grant type is used by clients to exchange a refresh token for an access token when the access token has expired.

This allows clients to continue to have a valid access token without further interaction with the user.

## Consider this.

Lets say that i add my login and password for my twitter account to your application and you then use that to request access from twitter to may account to post.  Three months later i have forgotten i have set your awesome app up to do something on my twitter account and i change my password.  Your system will break.

Now lets say i used Oauth2 to grant you access to my Google drive account, your awesome app can now do what ever it needs to do on my drive account.  Now three months latter i have again forgotten i gave your awesome app access,  I have the memory of a gold fish you see.  I change my password.  Nothing happens your awesome app still has access.

Now consider this, With oauth2 i can grant you access to only read from my google drive account not update it (scope).  That and the system knows its not actually me preforming the actions.

With client login (login and password) most of the time it appears to the system that it is the actually owner of the account making the requests.  You can also not limit access with client login for the most part you have full access.

## note

yes i am ignoring the part about both tokens returned being the expiration time time.  Thats because for all intensive purposes they are the same but that depends greatly on how the auth server you are using is set up.   They could be set up to only be valid for an hour or a day.  They may give you different access scopes, again this differs greatly from auth server to auth server.